# Integrate $\int{2^{2x}} dx$

Tags: integration

Integrate $$\int{2^{2x}} dx$$

How do I do it, at first, I thought I treat 2 as $e$ and I will get something like $\dfrac{1}{2} 2^{2x}$, but according to [WolframAlpha](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=2%5E%282x%29&random=false) its supposed to be $\dfrac{4^x}{\lg{4}}$

Comment: Why would you treat $2$ as $e$? At most, you can think of $2^x=e^{x \log 2}$ from where you can solve the given integral using $$\int e^{ax} dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a}$$
Also, note that $2^{2x} = 4^x = e^{x \log 4}$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, I was thinking both are constants so maybe they have the same properties

Comment: It isn't the case. $e$ is a *very special* constant.

Comment: If you just divide your answer by $\ln(2)$ then you'll get Wolfram's answer. And you're right, $2$ and $e$ are both constants and they almost share the same properties, at least relative to integration of the corresponding exponentials. $e^x$ is a bit cleaner though since dividing by $\ln(e)$ amounts to dividing by $1$..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, $$\frac{d}{dx}a^x = a^x \log a.$$ Hence $$\int a^x \, dx = \frac{1}{\log a}a^x+C.$$

Comment: Hmm, somehow ... I don't remember $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x \log{a}$ ... could you explain how do I get there, chain rule etc? Just to aid my understanding, I could of course add this into my formula sheet

Comment: Alternatively, you have $\int 2^{2x}\mathrm dx=\int \exp(x\log\,4)\mathrm dx$. Let $u=x\log\,4$ and remember how to integrate the natural exponential function...

Comment: @JiewMeng: simply write $a^x$ as $e^{x\log a}$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: These things are always a bit "circular". You need to know that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log a,$$ otherwise you are out of luck. But this is the definition of the derivative of $x \mapsto a^x$ at $x=0$. Exponential and logarithms should be either defined correctly, or taken as granted to some extent.

Answer (score 5):

First, rewrite
$$2^{2x} = (2^2)^x = 4^x.$$
This eliminates the need to do a substitution.  Then, use the rule that
$$\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x \ln a,$$
so that
$$\int a^x \,dx = \frac{a^x}{\ln a} + C.$$
If you don't see where this comes from, use logarithmic differentiation.  That is, let $y = a^x$.  Then, $\ln y = \ln a^x = x \ln a$.  Taking the derivative of both sides gives
$$\frac{y'}{y} = \ln a$$
so that
$$y' = y \ln a = a^x \ln a.$$
Now, it is simple to see that
$$\int 2^{2x} \,dx = \int 4^x \,dx = \frac{4^x}{\ln 4} + C.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ I = \int 2^{2x} \mathrm {d}x \tag{1}$$
Let

$$ \begin{align*}
y &=2^{2x} \hspace{5pt} \\
\Rightarrow \ln y &= 2x \ln 2
\end{align*}
$$

Differentiate both sides

$$ 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} &= 2 \ln 2 \\
\frac{dy}{y}&=
2 \ln 2 \hspace{4pt}dx\\ 
&= \ln 2^2 \hspace{4pt} dx
\end{align*}
$$

$$ 
\begin{align*}
dx &= \frac{dy}{y \hspace{4pt} \ln 2^2} 
\end{align*}
$$

Substitute for $x$ and $dx$ in $(1)$

$$ 
\begin{align*}
I &= \int y \frac{dy}{y \hspace{4pt} \ln 2^2}\\
&= \int \frac{1}{\ln 2^2} \mathrm{d}y =  \frac{1}{\ln 2^2} \int \mathrm{d}y =  \frac{1}{\ln 4} \int \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{y}{\ln 4} + C  \hspace{14pt} (\textit{But } y=2^{2x})\\
&= \frac{2^{2x}}{\ln 4} + C 
\end{align*}
$$